# Html5 object tag links not working

Tags: html

I'm trying to design a webpage, here I am including a header through the object tag.  what happens are two things:

Whenever the bar gets bigger than the innitial size, a scrollbar appears at the bottom of the header, instead of at the bottom of the page.

When I click a link, it opens a mini-window in the corner of the screen where the navbar was

Also, if I open the navbar as a seperate file, it works fine.

```
<object type="text/html" style="max-width:100%;" data="header.html">Header</object>
```

Here is my include script

Comment: are you using bootstrap?

Comment: What's bootstrap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try giving the object a max-width or add scrolling="no" to the object.

```
<object type="text/html" scrolling="no" style="max-width:100%;" data="header.html">Header-</object>
```

And try adding `<base target="_parent">` on top of your page, this might work against showing the clicked links in a window.

Comment: nope, same problem. Here's my <head> code: <base target="_parent">
  <object type="text/html" style="max-width:100%;" data="header.html">Header</object>

Comment: Edit: needed to put <base> in header, Thanks!